# Tkinter treeview resizing the treeview to fit screen

Tags: tkinter, resize, treeview

I am having a small issue with getting the treeview to resize to the tkinter window and can't seem to get an answer from google. The code below works fine except for the fact it seems to have a fixed size inside the "screen". I have tried various versions of "fill" and "stretch" but I just can't seem to get it right. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

screen = tk.Tk() 
screen.title('This One')
screen.geometry('890x400')

cols = ('TOKEN', 'F-500', 'F-250', 'F-100', 'F-24', 'POS','NEG', 'NULL', 'VOLUME', 'VOLUME-FUT', 'RPP')
box = ttk.Treeview(screen, columns=cols, show='headings')
for col in cols:
    box.heading(col, text=col)
    box.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)


box.column("TOKEN", width=95)
box.column("F-500", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-250", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-100", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-24", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("POS", width=75, anchor='center')
box.column("NEG", width=75, anchor='center')
box.column("NULL", width=75, anchor='center')
box.column("VOLUME", width=90, anchor='center')
box.column("VOLUME-FUT", width=90, anchor='center')
box.column("RPP", width=45, anchor='center')

showScores = tk.Button(screen, text="Update", width=15).grid(row=10, column=1)
closeButton = tk.Button(screen, text="Close", width=15, command=exit).grid(row=10, column=0)

screen.mainloop()
```

It might be a really simple thing but I just can't see it!

Thanks,

Mort

Comment: Ive added an answer, do let me know

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help. It doesn't seem to work for me as it now just makes the treeview stick to the bottom of the screen rather than fill the available space....When i go full screen with this window the treeview just sits at the bottom of the tkinter windo rather than expanding to fit the available space.

Comment: I didn't know about the screen.resizable which is great but this treeview will eventually have quite a lot of rows in it and it would be great to be able to resize it to see more than just the ten or so rows currently visable.

Comment: Ive updated the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saying this first:

```py
screen.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
screen.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

and make sure to also say `sticky='nsew'` for the treeview, like:

```py
box.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky='nsew') #say sticky='nsew'
```

Is this what you mean by fit to the screen? This will make sure the treeview always stays fit to the screen, when you resize the window.

Other way would be to disable resizing of the whole window, by saying `screen.resizable(0,0)`

Hope you found this answer helpful, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: Should be `screen.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)` because the `Treeview` is put in row 1.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!